# Using wand.image + python 2.7 to trim white space

Tags: python, image-processing, wand

Is there a good way to trim white borders around jpgs generated from a PDF using wand.image, or should I be using another package?  Note, the jpg's are images, with varying colors @ borders.  Code below generates the image files for each part.  Just have no clue how to trim out the white space

```
from wand.image import Image
f = "my_pdf.pdf"
with Image(file=f, resolution=72) as document:
    for page_number, page in enumerate(document.sequence):
        with Image(page) as img:
            img.compression_quality = 70
            bytes_io_file = BytesIO(img.make_blob('JPEG'))
```

my system: python 2.7 on ubuntu 16

thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the white space always representable with a rectangle?

Comment: good question. the page could have curved edges.

Comment: If you don't care about the sizes, you can just detect blobs and get the total of the bounding boxes.

Comment: thanks, sizes do not matter (don't need to be all the same), so you are right, i need to figure out the bounding from top, bottom, etc.  Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be a [`Image.trim`](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/wand/image.html#wand.image.Image.trim) method to do this.

```py
>>> from wand.image import Image
>>> from wand.color import Color
>>> with Image(filename="logo:") as img:
...   img.trim(Color("WHITE"))
...   img.save(filename="output.png")
```

[image: output.png]